# Writing and learning assembly on a Mac

Tags: assembly, x86, macos

I recently decided that I wanted to try learning how to program in assembly. Having a 2011 model MBP, I was not able to find much info on how to write and execute assembly code on my computer. If anyone could point me in the right direction on this (as well as provide any useful tutorials) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assembly Programming on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656485/assembly-programming-on-mac)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should help you further: [Learn NASM on OS X](http://zathras.de/angelweb/blog-learn-nasm-on-os-x.htm).

Comment: The main link, using NASM on OS X, is invalid.

Comment: If you read the comments on that site you'll find someone posted a link to [the archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20070830122645/http://untimedcode.com/2007/5/20/learn-nasm-assembly-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: OK, that may be, but who reads all the comments before clicking a link? I don't.

Comment: And now... The archived version has been removed to0!

Answer (score 2):

Try this article: [Assembly language programming under OS X with NASM](http://www.caswenson.com/2009_09_26_assembly_language_programming_under_os_x_with_nasm). It won't teach you x86 or x86-64 assembly language, but it tells you how to use it under OS X. There are many tutorials for x86 assembly language.

Comment: It may be broken now. It wasn't at the time of posting (Sept. 2011).

Comment: Oops, didn't see that! Sorry!

Comment: I fixed the link (may still be in peer review)